# Orchard Project Module getting error: No persister for: SomePartRecord

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, orchardcms

I am trying to create a simple setting in Orchard that appears in the settings page.   I have created a module which is adding my ContentPart to the settings page and is correctly creating a table in the database but every time the cshtml file is rendered and the property of the record is accessed I keep getting the following NHibernate Record.

No persister for: TekFlow.Contact.TekFlowEmailSettingsPartRecord.
(TekFlow.Contact is the Module name)

Below is all of the code that I am using to create the Record/Part/Handler/Driver needed in Orchard.

```
 public class TekFlowEmailSettingsPartDriver : ContentPartDriver<TekFlowEmailSettingsPart>
{
    public TekFlowEmailSettingsPartDriver()
    {
        T = NullLocalizer.Instance;
    }

    public Localizer T { get; set; }

    protected override DriverResult Editor(TekFlowEmailSettingsPart part, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {
        return ContentShape("Parts_TekFlowEmailSettings_Edit",
            () => shapeHelper.EditorTemplate(TemplateName: "Parts.TekFlowEmailSettings", Model: part, Prefix: Prefix)
                );
    }

    protected override DriverResult Editor(TekFlowEmailSettingsPart part, Orchard.ContentManagement.IUpdateModel updater, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {
        bool success = updater.TryUpdateModel(part, Prefix, null, null);
        return Editor(part, shapeHelper);
    }
}

[UsedImplicitly]
public class TekFlowEmailSettingsPartHandler : ContentHandler
{
    public TekFlowEmailSettingsPartHandler(IRepository<TekFlowEmailSettingsPartRecord> repository)
    {
        Filters.Add(new ActivatingFilter<TekFlowEmailSettingsPart>("Site"));
        Filters.Add(StorageFilter.For(repository));
    }
}

 public class TekFlowEmailSettingsPartRecord : ContentPartRecord {
     public virtual string SendToEmail { get; set; }
}

 public class TekFlowEmailSettingsPart : ContentPart<TekFlowEmailSettingsPartRecord>
 {
     public string SendToEmail
     {
         get { return Record.SendToEmail; }
         set { Record.SendToEmail = value; }
     }
 }

 public class TekFlowEmailSettingsDataMigration : DataMigrationImpl
 {
     public int Create()
     {
         SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("TekFlowEmailSettingsPartRecord",
             table => table
                 .ContentPartRecord()
                 .Column<string>("SendToEmail", c => c.WithDefault("SomeEmail@somedomain.com").WithLength(255))
             );


         ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition(
             typeof(TekFlowEmailSettingsPart).Name, cfg => cfg.Attachable());

         return 1;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you know there's two existing contact forms on the Gallery, and one of them is open source on CodePlex (shameless plug, I wrote it) http://contactform.codeplex.com/

Comment: Paul,  I actually tried your Module and logged two separate issues on CodePlex for it :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Turns out that if your Part and Record are not in your "Models" namespace that this wont work in orchard.   When I changed the Namespace for the two classes it worked.  Must be an assumption that Orchard is making.

Comment: That's correct - classes mapped to record must be in /Records or /Models folder by convention.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error from **not** having `virtual` variables in my record.
(In my case it did not inherit `ContentPartRecord` and declared its own `Id`, not sure if the issue simply was that `Id` was not `virtual` or that all variables had to be `virtual`.)

Also as mentioned above, your namespace must end with `Models` or `Records`, as explained here:
https://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/267968.

Answer (score 0):

My Favicon module has pretty much the same structure and when I did a file by file comparison I could not find a significant difference. The only thing that looks suspicious is that you didn't define a prefix in your driver. That may interfere with the binder's ability to rehydrate the model but I'm not sure how that would affect persistence.